# Java Open file with the right encoding

Tags: java, encoding

I have a folder with a series of .txt files with different encodings.

I have to open each file with the right one but I really don't know how to do it.
Each file has a string at the beginning which says what type of encoding is needed.

How can I do it?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. check this -https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "string at the beginning" consists of ASCII characters:

1. Open the file with `FileReader` and the encoding "ASCII".
2. Read the encoding string into a local variable.
3. Close the reader.
4. Open the file with `FileReader` and the correct encoding.
5. Skip over the encoding encoding string.
6. Process the rest of the file.
7. Close the reader.

AFAIK, there is no supported way to "change" the encoding of a `Reader` or `Writer` stack after it has been set.